# Content Types with field "clusters". Possible or is there a different solution?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

My dilemma is this. At the moment I have a content type called "equipment" that I want to have a taxonomy term that will give a type of equipment, based on the selected type I want a new "cluster" of fields and/or taxonomy terms to pop up.

There is likely a different/better way of organizing the data.  Creating a new content type for each type of equipment doesn't seem very elegant, especially if I want to create a view for all of the equipment.

Any leads on where I can find a solution to this? My brain has problems with decorator patterns in SQL as well.

Comment: If "elegant" is important factor, then there can't be objective answer to this question. Views shouldn't really be a problem.

Comment: It's not that important to me.  I am basically asking if there is any kind of standard for this.  As someone who is not yet working in software, I want to understand "best practices" when they are available.  Thanks!

Comment: See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/78364/16495

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest solution is to have a single content type, add all fields that you need in any possible situation, and use [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) to hide/show fields based on the chosen equipment type taxonomy term.